# UTF-8 in PHP mail() for ÜÖÄ

Tags: php, email, encoding, utf-8, sendmail

I have this PHP Code to send a Mail

```
            if(Input::has('email')){
                $to      = Input::get('email');
                $link    = 'blabla';
                $subject = 'blabla';
                $message = "Ü Ä Ö jfklsfjal";
                $headers = 'From: dontreply@asdf.com' . "\r\n" .
                    'Reply-To: dontreply@asdf.com' . "\r\n" .
                    'Content-Type: text/plain;charset=utf-8\r\n' . "\r\n" .
                    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

                mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
            }
```

Problem is, that it still doesnt send the Ö Ä etc. not right (but I just added the content-type)!

Does anybody have any idea why it doesnt work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your header is incorrect, because you have `\r\n` part of the content-type (which is wrapped in single quote), i.e.:

```
            $headers = 'From: dontreply@asdf.com' . "\r\n" .
                'Reply-To: dontreply@asdf.com' . "\r\n" .
                'Content-Type: text/plain;charset=utf-8\r\n' . "\r\n" .
-------------------------------------------------------^^^^
                'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
```

Try changing the above to:

```
            $headers = 'From: dontreply@asdf.com' . "\r\n" .
                'Reply-To: dontreply@asdf.com' . "\r\n" .
                'Content-Type: text/plain;charset=utf-8' . "\r\n" .
                'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
```

---

If that doesn't work, try this:

```
            $headers = 'From: dontreply@asdf.com' . "\r\n" .
                'Reply-To: dontreply@asdf.com' . "\r\n" .
                'Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8' . "\r\n" .
                'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
```